# ROS2 controller manager doesn´t work

Tags: gazebo, ros2-control, ros2-controllers

currently I am working on visualizing a drone in Gazebo. My base is the sjtu_drone. I am trying to control the propellers of my drone with ros2_control but when i start the ros2 controller manager the terminal says "Controller manager not available" after checking the node list. It appears a node named "simple_drone/controller_manager". How can I fix the issue that the controller manager starts in simple_drone?

Error in Terminal:

```
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710412893.630305338] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710412893.662219724] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710412893.662911110] [simple_drone.joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710412893.840692078] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Loading controller 'rotor_controller'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710412894.056333002] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'rotor_controller'
[gzserver-4] [ERROR] [1710412894.056406458] [simple_drone.rotor_controller]: 'joints' parameter was empty
[gzserver-4] [WARN] [1710412894.056439109] [simple_drone.rotor_controller]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[gzserver-4] [ERROR] [1710412894.056459593] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: After configuring, controller 'rotor_controller' is in state 'unconfigured' , expected inactive.
```

My Controller yaml-File:

```
simple_drone/controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10
    use_sim_time: true

    rotor_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

rotor_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - rotation1
      - rotation2
      - rotation3
      - rotation4
```

My controller.launch.py

```
def generate_launch_description():

    robot_description = ParameterValue(
        Command(
        [
            "xacro ",
            os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("drone_description"), "urdf", "drone.urdf.xacro")
        ]
        ),
        value_type=str
    )

    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}]
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "--controller-manager",
            "simple_drone/controller_manager"
        ]
    )

    rotor_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "rotor_controller",
            "--controller-manager",
            "simple_drone/controller_manager"
        ]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        robot_state_publisher,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        rotor_controller_spawner
    ])
```

My URDF.xacro: (only the transmission tag and gazebo tag)

````
<xacro:macro name="rotor1_transmission">
    <transmission name="rotation1_tran">
        <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
        <actuator name="rotation1_motor" role="actuator1"/>
        <joint name="rotation1" role="joint1">
            <mechanical_reduction>1.0</mechanical_reduction>
        </joint>
    </transmission>
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:macro name="rotor2_transmission">
    <transmission name="rotation2_tran">
        <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
        <actuator name="rotation2_motor" role="actuator2"/>
        <joint name="rotation2" role="joint2">
            <mechanical_reduction>1.0</mechanical_reduction>
        </joint>
    </transmission>
</xacro:macro>

...

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
      <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
      <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
      <parameters>$(find drone_bringup)/config/rotor_controller.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

```
````

Comment: try to run your nodes with `--debug` and also pin the output of `ros2 topic list`, it will be easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Link to topic list: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dFyRbAd4Y_l4vUfKl4pxCoGxQjWYSGDj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please don't upload pictures of your console output. Better add it as formatted text to your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please paste any code or console output as *code formatted text* and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)... it also makes it difficult to copy/paste.  Also, any additional information should be put in the answer and **not** in the comments. Comments are ephemeral in nature and tends to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

According to your console output, you have set a namespace. This is why the node name also includes your namespace.

You don't have to manually start a controller_manager: gazebo_ros2_control already creates one (see your console output).

Comment: Okay, but when I run the command "ros2 run controller_manager spawner velocity_controller" it says: "waiting for controller_manager node to exist" and then "Controller manager not available"

Comment: yes, because you have set the namespace as I said above. Remove it or set the same namespace for the spawner.

Comment: okay thank you very much! Now I've come to another error. I have set the update_rate for the controller_manager in my yaml file. However, the error message appears in the terminal saying that I did not set this update_rate.

Comment: please add the relevant code of your yaml file, otherwise it is hard to tell. You can also use rqt_dynamic_reconfigure (or ros2cli) to check if you really have set the parameter.

Comment: i have added the yaml File to my main question

Comment: where do you set the namespace? If I'm not mistaken, then you also have to add the namespace to the controller yaml

Comment: namespace is set in the drone.yaml and is called from there. 
So I just have to add "namespace=simple_drone"?
I have added the drone.yaml in the main question

Comment: I don't know your code, and where this drone.yaml is used.
But if you set a namespace, you also have to adjust that in the `My yaml-File:`, for example `/simple_drone/controller_manager:` in the first line.

Comment: I tried it but I still get the error message "waiting for controller_manager node to exist"
How can I delete the namespace for specially one node? such as /simple_drone/controller_manager

Comment: just don't set it.
What is the problem status now? Above you wrote that the update_rate is now the problem, not that the spawner can't find the cm

Comment: ah sorry the error "update_rate" is gone. Terminal says " Desired controller update period (0.1 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[simple_drone.gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded gazebo_ros2_control." This is fine. If I now want to start my launch file in which the velocity controller is located, I get the error message "waiting for /controller_manager to exist". I think that's because of the problem you described above. Do I have to set the namespace in my launch file too? I have attached it in my main question

Comment: Try to set the parameter `--controller-manager` of the spawners correctly. If you start with a `/`, it will be absolute and not adding the namespace. `controller_manager` or `/simple_drone/controller_manager` would do the job.

Comment: Thank you!! One step further!  As I try to run my launch file both controllers are loading in but my rotor_controller doesn't configure correctly. The terminal says that no joints are found in the parameters. I have attached the updated controller.yaml and launch file in my main question. I also have added the ros2_control and transmission tag in my urdf.xacro.

Comment: do i have to set the namespace for my rotor_controller too?

Comment: please open a new question, as this is out of scope of the original one.

Comment: check with `ros2 node list`, but I think you also have the namespace there

Comment: once again, check with rqt if the parameters are set. And use ros2cli and ros2controlcli to introspect your nodes and controllers